# Convert jira API response into HTML

Tags: php, jira, jira-rest-api

I am working on PHP application and facing and issue. Is there is any way to convert jira API response into working HTML.

Here are is the response i got:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wq4dQ.png)

Result I am looking for:

```
<h1>I am heading 1</h1>
<h2>I am heading 2</h2>
<h3>I am heading 3</h3>
<h4>I am heading 4</h4>
<h5>I am heading 5</h5>
<h6>I am heading 6</h6>
```

Please let me know if there is any solution.

documentaion
https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-issues/#api-rest-api-3-issue-post

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

I am calling this /rest/api/3/issue/{issueIdOrKey} REST API endpoint and I am
looking for a way to get the issue description in HTML.

All I have to do is to append the argument to expand the rendered fields to your REST API call, like in below example:

[https://NAME.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/{ISSUE-KEY_OR_ID}?expand=renderedFields](https://NAME.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/%7BISSUE-KEY_OR_ID%7D?expand=renderedFields)

This fix my issue